# Sharepoint Framework doesn't run jquery in .js file

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-framework

I'm starting out with Sharepoint framework and at this point I just want to play around and get familiar with the concepts.

I've created webparts with the Yeoman generator and launched them in the workbench. Then I installed jquery 'by the book' but when I try to run a script from another file, it doesn't run the jquery code. The jQuery inside the webpart.ts runs fine. What's going on ?

i've installed jquery using:

```
npm install @types/jquery@2.0.48 --save
```

config.json

```
  ...
  "externals": {

    "jquery": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js",
    "myScript":{
      "path": "./src/test.js",
      "globalName": "myScript"

    }
...
```

webpart.ts

```
...
import * as $ from 'jquery';
require('myScript');
...
public render(): void {
this.domElement.innerHTML = `
<div id='testDiv'>Not Changed?</div>
<div id='testDiv2'>Not Changed?</div> `
;


$(function(){
  $("#testDiv").html("Changed") // works
});
```

test.js

```
console.log("hi"); // this is logged
$(function(){  // error: $ is not defined
    console.log( $("#testDiv2").html());  
    $("#testDiv2").html("Changed")
});
```

It seems the script in the .js file runs before the innerhtml is rendered? How does this work?

Comment: If you have installed jquery locally in your package then why are you still giving cdn path in config.json??

Comment: Hi Ganesh thanks for your reply. I'm new to the framework and simply followed the steps in the book. How would I use the local file instead of the cdn? I can't find a file in the folder structure. Also - will this solve the issue I am facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **SPComponentLoader:**

```
import { SPComponentLoader } from '@microsoft/sp-loader';
```

Now you can load your external script inside **render()** method (or somewhere else), like this:

```
SPComponentLoader.loadScript('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js', {
    globalExportsName: 'jQuery'
}).then(($: any) => {
    $(function() {
        console.log('jQuery is loaded');
    });
    SPComponentLoader.loadScript('path_to_script', {}).then(() => {
        //...do something
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much!